# JSF:-Problem with the DataType and Action Listener

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, actionlistener

I am facing a problem with the dataType component and ActionListener on adding two specific component...

Code Snippet of JSF is:-

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg.org_SubscriberGroupId_1} " styleClass="intro" escape="false"/>
<h:outputLabel value="&nbsp;:&nbsp;" escape="false"/>
<h:inputText value="#{SubscriberServiceProfile.closedSubscriberGroupId1}" id="txtClosdGrup1" styleClass="textBox" label="#{msg.org_SubscriberGroupId_1}" />                                                     

<h:outputLabel value="#{msg.org_expiryDate_1}" styleClass="intro" escape="false"/>
<h:outputLabel value="&nbsp;:&nbsp;" escape="false"/>
<rich:calendar id="expiryDate1" value="#{SubscriberServiceProfile.dtExpiryDate1}" styleClass="textBox" datePattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" required="false" label="#{msg.org_expiryDate_1}" />
```

The code repeats 5 times...with different ids...and different indexes...

My backing Bean code is:-

```
public class ServiceProfile
{

private String closedubscriberGroupId1="0";
private String closedSubscriberGroupId2="0";
private String closedSubscriberGroupId3="0";
private String closedSubscriberGroupId4="0";
private String closedSubscriberGroupId5="0";
private Date dtExpiryDate1;
private Date dtExpiryDate2;
private Date dtExpiryDate3;
private Date dtExpiryDate4;
private Date dtExpiryDate5;

//respective getters and setters

public void create(ActionListener act)
{
//action listener code
}

}
```

The problem is with the dataType of either ClosedSubscriberGroup or Expiry date..
User will enter integer value in closedSubscriberGroup Id input field.

But the problem is that my actionListener is not getting fired until and unless I specify the values in all the 5 text boxes of closedSubscriberGroupId..No validation is there in JSF.Still it is not allowing me to submit the form and call actionListener.

What can be the possible problem..????..Is it the DataType??? or any other problem??...
Please guide me....

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?  You want to convert the text entered in the `<h:inputText  id="txtClosdGrup1" /> ` to the  java `Date` data type ?? Or you want to call a method of the bean whenever there are `onChange()` event on the  `<h:inputText  id="txtClosdGrup1" /> ` ??

Comment: Add <h:messages/> to the page and check if there are any validation errors occurred (or just review server log, validation error should be logged there).

Comment: @ken chan My basic need is that in inputText user will enter integer value...and for the rich:date type he will select a date from the calendar...There is no onchange event and all the values are passed to the backing bean only when form is submitted...There is no intermediate call to the Backing Bean....

Comment: @Andrey that is what I was keepin as a last option..But I guess there's no other way out of this problem....Will c by putting messages...

Comment: will putting these 10 entries(closedGroup and expirydate) inside a new panelGrid help the cause????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment , it seems that you want to set the values you enter in the `<h:inputText>` and `<rich:calendar>` to its backing beans  and invoke the bean method immediately whenever  onchange event on the  `<h:inputText>` and `<rich:calendar>` happens

You could use the `a4j:support` :

```
<rich:calendar value="#{bean.date}" styleClass="textBox" datePattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" required="false">
    <a4j:support event="onchanged" action="#{bean.onChangeDate}" ajaxSingle="true"/>
</rich:calendar>

<h:inputText value="#{bean.aString}"  styleClass="textBox">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{bean.onChangeText}"  ajaxSingle="true" />
</h:inputText>
```

It means that whenever onchange  events happen on `<h:inputText>` and `<rich:calendar>`  , an Ajax request will be fired to invoke the method specified by the `action` attribute. The `ajaxSingle` attribute is important here as it will set the values you entered  in the controls immediately  to its backing bean before the `action` are invoked.

Note that for the `rich:calendar` , the onchange event is **onchanged** instead of **onchange**

Reference:

- [a4j:support Demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/support.jsf?c=support&tab=usage)
- http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply..However I will put the entered values in backing bean only on form submit and not on ajax call...There are no intermediate ajax calls before the form submit...So after entering all the values user will click on <h:commandButton> and actionListener will get called. Inside this actionListener I am getting the values of these fields using getters..However due to the problem specified my ActionListener itself is not getting called until all the field values are entered..No Validation is there on my JSF..

Comment: @ankit If the action of the `<h:commandButton>` cannot be called  if some  fields are empty , it  means that you have some validation errors that prevent you from submitting the form in such cases . Add `<h:messages/>` to see if there are any validation errors occurred.